# Converting string to date iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following string:

> 01/27/2016 11:00:00

And I am passing it to this method:

```
-(NSDate*)dateFromString:(NSString*)dateString format:(NSString*)format {
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy, HH:mm:ss"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:strToConvert]);
}
```

and it is returning `nil`. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Edit:This only seems to be happening on the iPhone, on the iPad it functions fine.

Comment: What is `strToConvert`? your method does not have definition for that variable.

Comment: You need a date format specifier that actually matches your date string.

Comment: How can it work on one device and not another? The only possible way is that your actual string is different on the two devices. Please verify that.

Comment: `yy` ≠ `2016`, on any way.

Comment: Useful for Date Formats http://nsdateformatter.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
-(NSDate*)dateFromString:(NSString*)dateString format:(NSString*)format {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"]; //01/27/2016 11:00:00
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    return date;
}
```

Your code missing returning statement. I hope you would getting an error too.

Comment: The problem is the date format and the format in this answer  isn't even close.

Comment: He is not returning anything, he should get error also. He can't run the code. it seems. Updated format. I didn't observe that. Thanks.

Comment: day/month/year and hour:minutes:seconds. what is mistake @rmaddy

Comment: It's not day/month/year (what month is 27?). And it's not a two-digit year. Details matter. And where's the comma in the string?

Comment: @VS - check the year is wrong is not **yy** it is **yyyy**, check the year is **2016**

Comment: @VS - now also wrong bro is not **MM/dd/yyyy, HH:mm:ss** , it is **MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss** see the date is **01/27/2016 11:00:00**

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I need coffee, it seems :)

Comment: It's still incorrect. Have your coffee then come back.

Comment: maddy - the format is month/day/year, us, not european or most of the rest of the planet - so 27 is the day

Comment: Thanks @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @PruitIgoe Obviously. That was what I was trying to point out.